# How to show game screen in one viewport and minimap in another, with different sprites on each?

Tags: 2d, camera, godot, viewport, minimap

All tutorials I've found about this link to the splitscreen demo, but it is made under Godot version 2 and does not work in version 3.

I want to render the world in the main viewport and its simplified view on the minimap in another viewport using two different cameras.

In the main viewport the main `AnimatedSprite` node of objects should be rendered, and on the minimap there are only additional `Sprite` nodes of objects showing their schematic view.

I tried to do:

```
Node2D
-ViewportContainer
--ViewportMain
--- Camera2D
--- World
----Player
-----AnimatedSprite # for main viewport
-----Sprite # for minimap
----OtherObjects
-----AnimatedSprite # for main viewport
-----Sprite # for minimap
-ViewportContainer
--ViewportMinimap
--- Camera2D
```

In code I assign the main viewport's world to the minimap's viewport:

```
$ ViewportMinimap.world = $ ViewportMain.world
```

For the main `AnimatedSprite` I set Light Layer #1, for the sketchy `Sprite` I set Light Layer #2.

And it does not work.

Firstly, nothing is displayed on the minimap. I don’t understand how to make it work. How to tell the minimap's viewport to use the world from the main viewport?

Secondly, I can’t find anywhere how to set on the camera which Light Layer it has to display (in the three-dimensional Camera there is a Cull Layer parameter, but I don’t see it here).

Will this approach hit performance?

How to correctly implement a minimap without needing to modify it when you add new objects to the game?

How to correctly replace scenes when player moves from one to another if it's a child of the Viewport?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. Here is project with working solution: https://gamedev.ru/files/?id=146737

I should to use world_2d instead of world variable.

```
$ViewportMinimap.world_2d = $ViewportMain.world_2d
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it walked through the steps of your solution, rather than relying on an external link that can rot.

Comment: Could you give even just an image of the code you used?
It would really help me understand how to implement it.
Thanks!